# LKM code to retrieve all process id ,ppid ,status ,process scheduled time and so on

Tags: linux-kernel

lkm code to function same as ps aux command.on using ps aux command we get information about process. Those details should be obtained by writing LKM code .

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you expect to achieve by posting such a bad question? First off it is obvious that's not the problem specification because username resolution from the kernel would be a disaster. Also it was not specified how the data was to be exported. As for iterating over a list of processes and obtaining various data present in the kernel, I fail to see what's the problem.

http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html